# HTML Canvas - diagonal line looks "choppy"

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

In drawing diagonal lines in canvas element using <s>ctx.moveTo</s> ctx.lineTo(), I find they have a "choppy" appearance, almost like they are dotted, with darker and lighter segments.  I have tried setting/unsetting ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled (which has no effect.)  It appears that aliasing is controlled by the OS so I have no control over this.  After much searching I have not found a solution.  Anyone have a suggestion or explanation?

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 20);
ctx.lineTo(200, 40);

ctx.moveTo(0, 40);
ctx.lineTo(200, 80);

ctx.stroke();
```

Here is a working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ub0fcq3n/4/)

Answer (score 0):

In short search for **high density display + canvas** for more info on this topic, a lot has been written.

Compare your lines to: https://jsfiddle.net/hycbona0/

Note how I am setting the canvas width/height and setting the CSS width/height of the canvas to be *half* the canvas width/height.

```
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 300;
```

And:

```
canvas {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

This means that there are twice as many canvas pixels per CSS pixel, which will make it look much better on high density displays.

Comment: Actually, it does not look any better, and I see no difference other than you repeat drawing the first two lines over themselves by calling stroke() after each lineTo().  By removing the intermediary stroke()s they look exactly the same on my 1920x1080 display: https://jsfiddle.net/d9fo0rvm/